# Como sacar el primer elemento de una lista que esta dentro de otra lista

Tags: python, lista

```
nombres = ["Martin", "Mili", "Anastasia", "Lupita", "Tomasa", "Pelusa", "Genoveva", "Motita"]
tipos = ["canino", "canino", "felino", "felino", "felino", "canino", "bovino", "roedor"]
edades = [12, 9, 10, 8, 9, 2, 14, 1]
pesos = [33, 26, 4, 5, 5, 6, 106.4, 0.34]

veterinaria = [nombres, tipos, edades, pesos]
```

Tengo la lista "veterinaria" y adentro 4 listas (nombres, tipos, edades, pesos).
**Lo que quisiera hacer es sacar con un for el primer elemento de la primera lista (nombres) dentro de  la lista "veterinaria".**

He intentado con este código:

```
caninofull = []

for nombre in veterinaria:
    caninofull.append(veterinaria[0][0])
```

Pero cuando imprimo la variable *caninofull* en el Visual Studio Code me sale repetido 4 veces así:

```
['Martin', 'Martin', 'Martin', 'Martin']
```

Y yo solo quiero que me salga una sola vez. ¿Cómo le hago o que cambio o que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Si quieres que el nombre "te salga una sola vez" entonces por qué quieres hacerlo con un `for`? Solo lee el nombre directamente con `veterinaria[0][0]`

Comment: Buen día, yo creo que tienes un error de concepto, los ciclos `for` se usan para iterar (Recorrer) un objeto iterable (Rango, lista o diccionario), con la línea `for nombre in veterinaria:` lo que haces es que el iterador `nombre` obtenga los valores de `nombres`, `tipos`, `edades` y `pesos` (Por eso te sale 4 veces). [Lectura recomendada](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/bucle-for-en-python-ejemplo-de-for-i-en-range/). Si deseas únicamente el primer valor de tu lista de `nombres` entonces usa `veterinaria[0][0]` sin usar el `for` como recomendó @FedericoMeza

Comment: Si lo que esperas es algo diferente entonces edita tu pregunta y explica ¿Por qué necesitas el `for`?